# How to remove DOM element based on selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to stop a person from editing a DOM element from the Developer console. I saw ==$0 and so on till $4(Google Chrome), which denotes the current selection previous selection and so on, so can I use this somehow or if you can suggest anything else will be of great help.

I just want to stop a person from editing an element from the Developer console, even if I have to remove it as soon as he/she selects it that is okay with me. But it should stop him/her from editing it.

Comment: from a chrome extension or a simple web page?

Comment: short answer: you can't

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. As soon as the DOM is loaded on the user side, he is also able to manipulated it with the developer console.

Also check out:
[How to prevent html/JavaScript code modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118986/how-to-prevent-html-javascript-code-modification)

Answer (score 0):

Just disbale the element inspector option from right click, `F12` key and combination `ctrl + shift + i`. You can find the required documentations on the web. And no one will be able to open the developers' console.

Comment: Thanks, this can be done, at least it'll be a pain if client side changes are to be done.

Comment: You can use the enabled version in your development/local units and disable these features in production.

Comment: if you have the developer console open before you reach the site what do you do then?

Comment: you can still open it via the menu

Comment: There are many ways to open the developer console. Which all can't be disabled. The encryption might help but once the page is loaded on the client side, nothing can be done. The best can be done is by mnifying the html, css and js to unreadable formats. Use server side validations and prevent code injections.

Comment: Thanks guys for the insights.