# I want to know if someone can manipulate my HTML code with inspect element?

Tags: php, html, json, string, forms

i want to know if a user in my game can manipulate this code through inspect element. Specifically the gift shop, will appreciate any help i can get.

```
How Many <select class="areatestsmall" name="amount">
<option value="1">1</option>
```

[Here is the HTML code](https://pastebin.com/iSg28L7G)

Comment: yes someone can

Comment: yes, they can. Someone could even make a HTTP request and send data to your PHP script without using a browser at all (for example, using a tool such as PostMan, or any other HTTP client). Therefore, your server-side code to needs to be written in such a way that it validates all incoming input (e.g. querystring values, submitted form data), to check if it makes sense or not. (Again as an example, a sanity check could include "is this value a valid date", or "is the current user allowed to choose that option")

Comment: can you show me how through screenshare?

Comment: No need to screenshare. These tools are heavily documented online. On most browsers, you press F12 to open the Developer Tools. Or there is usually a menu option. Or you can right-click a specific area on the page and click "Inspect" from the context menu. Then in the "Elements" section of the developer tools you can click / right-click on elements to edit their contents, or to add/remove items in the page. Or someone could submit JavaScript via the Console which could change the page contents. Conclusion: your server-side code must **never** any trust input coming from the client

Comment: HTML is public and changeable by anybody in the browser. Simple answer is: yes.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the comments have said yes this is possible and easy to do. One way to get around this is to assign each option and ID and then store the value of associated with any one ID in a database. When a use clicks an option you look up that ID and get the amount that way.

Answer (score 0):

Once the content is delivered to the client (browser), you don't really own it any more, so users (and also yourself) can modify it at will.

There are some ways to get some control but no way to avoid it, as stated at this question of SO [How to prevent html/JavaScript code modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118986/how-to-prevent-html-javascript-code-modification):

- Most important: you should **always validate any data reaching your back-end** before processing it if possible.
- You can wait until the user does your desired action, and then load the content.
- You can use [DOM events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) to control when your elements are being altered and react to these actions.