# Running a function that creates a click event twice causes the click event to happen twice with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm working on a game but I boiled down the functionality here.

TestA() is designed to create a click event on a certain object. When that object is clicked, it updates an array, tester.

The click event shouldn't ALWAYS be there, which is why I create it with `TestA()`, and then turn it off inside of `TestA()`.

However, when I run two `TestA()` functions back-to-back, the array updates twice on one click, instead of the expected behavior of once, then I need to click again for the second update.

I'm trying to test:

```
var tester = []

function TestA() {   
  $("someobject").click(function () {
    tester.push("hello")
    $(this).off()
  })
}

TestA()
```

----> running this by itself once makes `tester = ["hello"]` after one click.

```
TestA()
TestA()
```

-------> running these two back-to-back, after ONE click tester becomes `["hello","hello]`

I understand that Javascript will evaluate everything simultaneously (I posted a similar question in the past), but I do need to make sure people can't cheat in this game!

Again, my goal is to have `TestA()` add the click event, have it work once on click and not again until the second `TestA()` puts the event out again.

-I suppose a workaround is to have event listeners all over the place with an "if" inside its function that checks to see if the function can even be evaluated upon a click - but I'd much rather only create the click events in small windows of time.

Comment: `TestA()` adds an event handler.  Calling it twice adds 2 event handlers. The 2nd does not replace the 1st, they stack up, even if they're identical.  They don't actually execute until the event is fired, so the `.off()` functionality doesn't prevent 2 (or more!) handlers from being created.  When you click, any and all attached event handlers will fire - 2 in this case.  As you say, they run simultaneously, so you get the results you are seeing.

Comment: Rather than adding and removing event handlers, another option might be to track the state.  Set up all your handlers initially, and when they fire test the current state to see if they should do anything.  As a simple example `TestA()` would not include adding an event handler (that would be added at page load, or game start, or whatever), or removing it, but just test if `tester` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
var tester = []

function TestA() {
  // First remove click handler and set a new one
  $("someobject").off("click").one("click", function () {
    tester.push("hello")
  })
}

TestA()
```

Here is a small example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yusmneb1/

**Please note**: To achieve some kind of cheating protection, you should consider server side validation of your game logic. Javascript can be manipulated by the user easily. Here is a link to a question about that topic: [How to prevent html/JavaScript code modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118986/how-to-prevent-html-javascript-code-modification)

Comment: Thank you! I clicked, and once it pushed "hello" once to tester, the click didn't register anymore.

Maybe I didn't describe it right - what I'm looking for is for each run of testA() to be its own discrete application of the click function, so I'd click once and ["hello"] would show up. Then i'd click again and ["hello","hello"] would show up.

I also plan to develop the server side tool, so maybe what I'm asking for isn't possible, I was just hoping to test iterating this function to see if it would work, albeit in a way that it wouldn't even be used in the actual game I don't think.

Comment: You are welcome. I simply removed the line `$(this).off("click")` from click handler. That did the trick and I updated the jsfiddle link as well. So please check if it mets you requierments now. Let me know.

Comment: I also made use of the `one` function @cars10m mentioned. I think this is a better approach than using `$(this).off("click")` within the click handler. Credits to him. Please check the JSFiddle link again. I didn't want to steal that idea but I guess the most important thing is a working and good solution.

Comment: The jsfiddle now contains another element which calls the `testA()` function on click and adds a new oneshot click event to the `click me` element.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery `.one()` you can probably achieve what you want: the associated event will be triggered once only:

```js
const arr=[];
function clickOnOff(flag){
  let b=$("button").off("click");
  if(flag) b.one("click",ev=>{
   arr.push("click");
   $("#switch").prop("checked",false);
   console.log(arr)
  });
}
$("#switch").click(function(){clickOnOff(this.checked)});
// even multiple activation will result in a SINGLE click response:
clickOnOff(1);clickOnOff(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="switch" checked /> listening ...</label><br>
<button>click</button>
```